# App Script Conditional Format Rules from String Array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a tournament bracket with google sheets to use with my wife. I used conditional formatting to check if our guess is correct. This is an example of the formula for a correct answer, which highlights the cell green: `=MATCH(B5, INDIRECT("S6 Official!B5"), 0)`. Similar logic is used to check for an incorrect answer for each cell containing a bracket entry. For a tournament of 32 teams, that means there are 62 conditional format rules per bracket. My problem is using the bracket for another season. Until now, I've been manually changing all the format rules to the newer sheet, I just got tired of doing it. I began to wonder if I could do it programmatically. Here's what I came up with so far:

```
function setFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Name S6');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Name S7');

  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var rules2 = []
  for (i=0; i < rules.length; i++) {
    var bool = rules[i].getBooleanCondition();
    var rule = bool.getCriteriaValues();
    rule = rule.toString().replace("S6", "S7");
    rule = rule.toString().replace("S6", "S7");
    rules2.push(rule);
  }
}
```

I am able to get the format rules into an array of ConditionalFormatRules, and then use that array to create a new array that takes each rule's text and changes instances of "S6" to "S7" (when I get the logic down, I can replace these with variables so I can do it for any sheet) (also, there are two replace lines, as the 'wrong' format rules reference the 'SX Official' sheet twice).

Now, however, I'm stuck as I don't know how to get a String array to convert to an array of ConditionalFormatRules (or if it's even possible) and push it to the new sheet. Alternatively, my problem would be subverted if there was a way to only have two format rules, one for right and one for wrong, for the entire sheet, and the formula would be able to be used for any corresponding cell, but I didn't know how to do that either.

Comment: Can you please share a sample or copy of your spreadsheet so we can easily replicate what you have? Remove sensitive data if any. Also if possible share screenshots of input and desired output so we can clearly understand your goal.

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.